# func return does notReturn String from my conform to protocol StringLiteralConvertible error

Tags: ios, string, swift

I have class which has the func of return path to some file:

```
func getArchivePathFor(fileName: String!) -> String {
        var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String     
        var path: String = paths.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName!)
        return path    
    }
```

But when I try to use it in my code like:

```
let val = Helpers.getArchivePathFor("MyList.plist")
```

I get the error: "Return String from my func return does not conform to protocol StringLiteralConvertible error". Why so?

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring a instance method, whereas `Helpers.getArchivePathFor("MyList.plist")` is calling a class method.

If you want to declare a class method, try prefix `class`:

```
class Helpers {
    class func getArchivePathFor(fileName: String!) -> String {
    ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is quite misleading in this case. It seems you are using `getArchivePathFor` as class function. But its declared as instance function. Try:

```
class func getArchivePathFor(fileName: String!) -> String {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
struct  Helper 
{
static func getArchivePathFor(fileName: String!) -> String 
{
    var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    var path: String = paths.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName!)
    return path
}
}
```